# How to prove or disprove:$\inf_i{\sup_x\{f_i(x)+g_i(x)}\} \leq \inf_i{\sup_x{f_i(x)}} + \inf_i{\sup_x{g_i(x)}}$

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

How to prove or disprove:$$\inf_i{\sup_x\{f_i(x)+g_i(x)}\} \leq \inf_i{\sup_x{f_i(x)}} + \inf_i{\sup_x{g_i(x)}}$$,

because,

$f_i(x) \leq \sup\limits_x{f_i(x)}$ and $g_i(x) \leq \sup\limits_x{g_i(x)}$

$\Rightarrow f_i(x) +g_i(x) \leq \sup\limits_x{f_i(x)} + \sup\limits_x{g_i(x)} $

but when I put the infimo I can not get out of it. Help please.

Edit. my space is $\mathbb{R}^3$, I forgot to put information that I think will be important. $f_i, g_i \geq 0$

Comment: It's not true. To find a counterexample, take $X$ to contain just one point.

Comment: right but if i'm in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: Then take the functions $f_i, g_i$ to be constant functions, only depending on $i$, for example $f_1 =1 =g_2$ and $f_2 = -1 = g_1$.

Comment: Sorry, i agree with you, but I forgot to put information that I think will be important. $f_i \geq 0$ e $g_i \geq 0$

Comment: Doesn't matter. Take $f_1 = 5 = g_2$ and $f_2 = 0 = g_1$. Then the left hand side is 5, but the right hand side is 0.

Comment: thank you very much, it helped a lot

Comment: I was trying to transform this problem:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3346231/is-dxt-yt-a-metric
in something more seen, but thanks! if you can help this other problem, thank you.

Comment: @PhoemueX Why not an official answer?

Comment: I couldn't take this example of yours to this other problem

Comment: because I need to show that: $\min \max \rho(x(t),z(t)) \leq \min \max \rho(x(t),y(t))+\min \max \rho(y(t),z(t)).$